# Using threads in this case?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method that essentially copies files from a remote system to our local system. This method needs to be executed 4 times during an hour, once every 15 minutes. The method is called with Period as parameter, where Period ranges from 0-3 (0 = Min:0-15; 3 = Min:45-0).

How can I run these as separate threads and then stop all of them before the next hour :20 comes so that I can invoke external program ProcessFiles.EXE? I can always continue threading, but I have no idea how thread-safe the program that reads the files is. So I prefer cutting all threads before the next :20 comes around.

Before, the 15-minute window was more than enough to copy all the files that fell into this 15-minute window. Unfortunately, this process has become very slow. So, assuming that I'm running the first IF statement (at :20), instead of just stopping it when I reach minute 35, I can let it run in a thread until the end of the hour. But if it hasn't completed after the next :20, then the thread needs to be stopped.

Edit: This used to be in a Task Scheduler. The Task would copy the 20 files for its respective 15-minute timeframe. Unfortunately, the file copying has become very slow. So now, in certain blocks, the file copy is taking a bit more than 15 minutes.

So my initial thought was to thread these processes. In the case of the 1st 15-minute block (the IF statement that runs in **Minute 20** that copies files from Min.00 to Min.1), let's say I use a thread. That means, that even if doesn't complete by **Minute 35** (where the process of copying Min.15-Min.30 begins), it still has until **Minute 20** of the next iteration (the first IF statement of the loop).

The disadvantage of the Scheduler is that if the Task doesn't complete on time, it will 1) block the Scheduler from running the task again, or 2) if I force it to close, copy only a portion of what to be copied.

Here's some of my code, so you have an idea of what I'm working with:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime DateNow = new DateTime(2014, 3, 1, 5, 0, 0); //For the example, start at 5AM.
    Thread thread0 ;
    Thread thread1 ;
    Thread thread2 ;
    Thread thread3 ;
    for (; ; ) //infinite loop
    {
        //DateNow will usually be DateTime.Now.
        if (DateNow.Minute == 20)
        {
            //Copy files from 5:00-5:15.
            //IF any of the threads from Hour 4 are still running, they must be stopped
            _CurrentHour = DateNow.Hour;
            thread0 = new Thread(() => CopyFiles(_CurrentHour, 0));
            thread0.Start();
        }
        else if (DateNow.Minute == 35)
        {
            //Copy files from 5:15-5:30.
            thread1 = new Thread(() => CopyFiles(_CurrentHour, 1));
            thread1.Start();
        }
        else if (DateNow.Minute == 50)
        {
            //Copy files from 5:30-5:45.
            thread2 = new Thread(() => CopyFiles(_CurrentHour, 2));
            thread2.Start();
        }
        else if (DateNow.Minute == 5)
        {
            //Copy files from 5:45-6:00.
            thread3 = new Thread(() => CopyFiles(_CurrentHour, 3));
            thread3.Start();
        }
        thread0.Join(); 
        thread1.Join();
        thread2.Join();
        thread3.Join();
        //CALL ProcessFiles.EXE

    }       
}
```

Comment: Is the "something else" another program? Cross-process thread synchronization is highly non-trivial.

Comment: "something else" is another program.

Comment: how does this not throw null refs?  your infinite loop only creates thread0,1,2,3 based on minutes...

Comment: Can you guarantee that all threads will complete their necessary work before the "top of the hour"?  What if Main() starts running part-way through the hour?

Comment: Don't you get `NullReferenceException`? Hard to believe.

Comment: @EricJ.: That's the problem, I want to stop them before the top-of-the-hour and then run the other program.

Comment: This really sounds like something better suited to the default Windows task scheduler which includes the ability to terminate previous iterations if they run too long and to kick off other tasks upon completion.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @Servy: you're adding words where they don't exist. Please read the post again.

Comment: @user3605366 The only way your code won't throw a NRE is if it takes 15 minutes to start a new thread.  If that's not the case, you'll get those exceptions.

Comment: Usually, the files that correspond to a 15-min chunk are copied before the 15-mins are up. But lately the remote server is slow and they take longer than the 15 minutes.

Comment: @Servy I don't get it. Even if it takes 15 mins also, when it comes to `Join` it will throw NRE for sure. I guess you misread the `else if` as `if statements`

Comment: @Servy: The files are available in 15-minute cycles. So when the next IF is run, there are already files to copy. And the 20-minute IF may also be running.

Comment: @ChrisHaas: It used to be in the Task Scheduler. But I've tested it and there's a greater chance of copying all the files if I thread every 15-minute files. That way, ideally, every 15-minutes has 1-hour to complete.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Quite right.  It'll throw an exception no matter what.

Comment: @SteveMitcham: I'm using Framework 4.

Comment: I'll agree with the others that this code doesn't look like it could possibly execute successfully.  You don't have any guarantee that all four thread exist at the time you are calling the joins.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but the task scheduler includes the ability to run every 15 minutes all day long and auto-kill after 1 hour.

Comment: @user3605366 in your response to Chris, can you explain more what 'if I thread every 15-minute files' means?  From your description it looks like the first set has about an hour to copy, the second 45 minutes, the third 30 minutes and the last 15 minutes.  So if you made 4 tasks in the scheduler with those timeouts you would achieve the effect you are looking for

Comment: @SteveMitcham: I'm not sure how thread-safe the EXE generated by the project will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using Tasks and Cancellation Tokens.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In this way you can cancel the tasks, then poll the tasks to wait until they are done/canceled  before moving on to the next step.

Comment: I ended up using Cancellation Tokens.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are looking for two things.

1. A periodic timer. These come in .NET in [multiple flavors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx). You would schedule your timer to execute every 15 minutes, and depending on which quarter or the hour it is, you decide which files to copy.
2. Queuing a unit of work to execute on a worker thread. Again here you have multiple options, ranging from using the managed thread pool (via [ThreadPool API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx) directly) or via the [Task API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (easier), or rolling your own (similar to what you tried to do which is more complicated but better suited for long-running tasks)

To address your other concern, regarding stopping the worker threads within the 15 minute window, the best option is to make this the responsibility of the worker threads. You should record the start time of your file operations when the timer is triggered, and in the worker threads periodically check whether the elapsed time is less than your desired length (15 minutes). If the thread detects it's getting close to the limit it should gracefully stop its processing and, perhaps, notify the rest of your application or system about the fact that it did not finish.

Answer (score -2):

In the first thread, wait 15 minutes and then copy the file:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 15); // 15 mins
```

If you want to kill the thread, you can call Abort function:

```
thread1.Abort();
```

Comment: thread.Abort() is a very bad idea.  Thread termination should be cooperative.

Comment: `Sleep()` is also not entirely reliable - it may not be exactly 15 minutes, despite what the thread is requesting.